# django-filter: How to filter by field A but display field B as corresponding filter option/text?

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a Django `Post` model with a fk to a `Category` model with a category name and a category slug. Now I filter these posts by category via [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and the [LinkWidget](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/widgets.html#linkwidget). That's fine and worked via `name="categories__name"` out of the box:

```
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

---

```
# filters.py
class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    categories = django_filters.AllValuesFilter(
        name="categories__name",
        label="Categories",
        widget=LinkWidget(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['categories',]
```

---

```
# template.html

<h2>Filter</h2>
{% for choice in filter.form.categories %}
   {{ choice }}    
{% endfor %}

<h2>Posts</h2>
<ol>
{% for obj in filter.qs %}
    <li>{{ obj.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But now I would like to eliminate the `categories__name` as the GET parameter and use `categories__slug` instead - but keep the more human readable `categories__name` as the link text in the `LinkWidget` - but I have no idea how to achieve this, any hints?

Some renderd html snippets:

Filtering via `name=categories__slug`:

```
<ul id="id_categories">
    <li><a href="?categories=audio-and-video">audio-and-video</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categories=bits-bytes">bits-bytes</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categories=foo-and-bar">foo-and-bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Filtering via `name=categories__name`:

```
<ul id="id_categories">
    <li><a href="?categories=Audio+and+Video">Audio and Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categories=Bits%2FBytes">Bits/Bytes</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categories=Foo+and+Bar">Foo and Bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

But what I want is (pseudocode):

```
<li><a href="?categories={{ category.slug }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
```

... and rendered:

```
<ul id="id_categories">
    <li><a href="?categories=audio-and-video">Audio and Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categories=bits-bytes">Bits/Bytes</a></li>
    <li><a href="?categories=foo-and-bar">Foo and Bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Perhaps it's easier to review this issue in a minimal, complete django project, so I made one: https://gitlab.com/tombreit/django-filter-demo

Versions:

- Python 3.5.3
- Django (1.10.7)
- django-filter (1.0.4)

Comment: Are you sure it works with `categories__name` GET-parameter out of the box but not  `?categories=`? What version of django-filter do you use?

Comment: With filtering by `categories__name` and  `Category.name` is `Audio and Video`, the GET parameter is `?categories=Audio+and+Video`. That worked. But I would prefer filtering by `categories__slug`, which would be `audio-and-video`, but keep the `category__name` string as the filter link text. Updated question to contain the python package versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
class CustomAllValuesFilter(django_filters.ChoiceFilter):
    @property
    def field(self):
        qs = self.model._default_manager.distinct()
        qs = qs.order_by(self.name).values_list(self.name, self.extra['choice_name'])
        del self.extra['choice_name']
        self.extra['choices'] = list(qs)
        return super(CustomAllValuesFilter, self).field


class PostFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    categories = CustomAllValuesFilter(
        name="categories__slug",
        label="Categories",
        widget=LinkWidget(),
        choice_name="categories__name"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['categories',]
```

Comment: Sorry for the errors in my model definition - I updated the question. The code in my question is some kind of pseudo code. The "real" model is a wagtail `Page` model linked via `ParentalManyToManyField` to the category model. I tried your suggestion, but setting `categories__name = django_filters.AllValuesFilter` caused the whole filter to disappear...

Comment: I'm not familiar with wagtail, sorry. With Django's models like in your updated code it works as expected -  shows slugs of all сategories already linked with posts.

Comment: Dear @sergey-zherevchuk, I've set up a minimal django project (no wagtail etc.) to replicate your answer, but it does not work, as stated in my previous comment. If you have time to spare, I kindly invite you to have a look at this demo project. The gitlab repository URL was added to the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've checked it. You forgot to update your template. Render filter form with `{{filter.form}}` to show slugs.

Comment: I've created a [new branch](https://gitlab.com/tombreit/django-filter-demo/tree/sergey-zherevchuk) testing your proposed solution, added your template rendering via `{{ filter.form }}` but I still do not get `categories__name` as link text for my categories filter. The filtering via `categories__slug` is working as expected.

Comment: Can you provide what link you expected and what you get?

Comment: Sure - I've [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44854719/revisions)  the question accordingly.

Comment: Got it, in that case you should customize `AllValuesFilter.field`. I'll try to update an answer little bit later.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot, dear @sergey-zherevchuk